# What causes Python Pytube to send me a HTTP ERROR 410 each time

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, pytube, http-status-code-410

I want to make a small python project and I am quite new with it. So I thought a youtube-downloader is a funny project to go by. So I looked at the documents about how to and installed everything accordingly. Now I am facing a strange 410 error. I searched on this platform the issue and some were resolved due an answer and some stayed open without closure.

The answers I found is if I(You) have the right pytube version installed. Besides that answer there was also a git repository available which I tried and it didn't work. That one is

`pip install git+https://github.com/Zeecka/pytube@fix_1060`

With this I still get the same error.
[image: This is the error]

Anybody any clue what I do wrong? Every other example I see and want to recreate to make sure it works just doesn't for me. I feel like I misplaced a package somewhere and that's how it's poorly/unreadable.

Python version: Python 3.10.2,
pip 21.2.4 from C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)